# Css change on value change in input field. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```js
var footerEmail = $('footer#footer input.email');
        var footerEmailLength = footerEmail.val().length;
        var footerEmailCaptcha = $("footer#footer .captcha-hide");

        footerEmail.focus( function() {
            footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","block");
        });


        footerEmail.blur( function() {
            if(footerEmailLength > 0) {
                footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","block");
            }
            else if (footerEmailLength == 0) {
                footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","none");
            }
        });
```

```css
.captcha-hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="footer">
  <input class='email'>
  <div class="captcha-hide">Testing</div>
</footer>
```

I want to make sure that onblur works when I enter something inside the text (input) field.

First if condition inside the blur function is not working since it is taking the value as '0' which will be initially. When I enter something and click outside of the input field then the css should be display:block

Please guide me how I can proceed further. I am new to jQuery/Javascript. Googling around to learn stuff.

Comment: Its kinda hard for us to help you specific without seeing all relevant code, HTML CSS

Comment: Your selectors are ridiculously long. As `id` should be unique within the DOM you can shorten it to `#footer-subscriber-form .form-item-mail input.email` at most, probably even less than that. Caching the object would help too

Comment: You're already creating a `footerEmail` variable. Why not use it in subsequent code instead of repeating that overly long selector?

Comment: I will edit and come back in few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give the `var footerEmailLength = footerEmail.val().length;` inside blur function.

The blur function should be like this:

```
footerEmail.blur( function() {
        var footerEmailLength = footerEmail.val().length;
        if(footerEmailLength > 0) {
            footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","block");
        }
        else if (footerEmailLength == 0) {
            footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","none");
        }
```

And if you use class as selector then change the `footerEmail.val().length`
to **`footerEmail[0].val().length`**.

The running code

```js
var footerEmail = $('.email');
        
        var footerEmailCaptcha = $(".captcha-hide");


footerEmail.focus( function() {
            footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","block");
        });


        footerEmail.blur( function() {
            var footerEmailLength = footerEmail[0].val().length;
            if(footerEmailLength > 0) {
                footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","block");
            }
            else if (footerEmailLength == 0) {
                footerEmailCaptcha.css("display","none");
            }
        });
```

```css
.captcha-hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="footer">
  <input class='email'>
  <div class="captcha-hide">Testing</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. It made sense to me now.